# Do I have to do camera calibration every shoot?

Tags: color, color-management, white-balance

I bought a xrite color checker export.

I understand that for white balance, I'm suppose to shoot the card every shoot. Because the whitebalance is different in every environment.

But what about camera calibration? The software it came with has the ability to create a camera profile from using the card. Do I also do this every single shoot? Or is this something I only have to do once for each camera+lens combo?

Comment: You don't need the "perfect" white balance with every shot, in reality this goal is unachievable anyway as there are so many different reflections, light sources, etc in real environment. And white balance itself might be used for creative effects too, say, what's the point of shooting in sunset without this golden glow?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to calibrate every shot.  Set white balance to kelvin and get it where you like it for the scene. (Never use AWB)  If the lighting changes, also change the white balance and reshoot the card. If you never have to change white balance but go from outdoor lighting to indoor lighting, reshoot the card when you go to artificial light.  That will help keep colors more accurate.

Comment: What's so awful about AWB?

Comment: AWB is uncontrolled so if your WB changes because the illumination changes, so will your camera calibration.